# Want my swing application with MS ACCESS database connection to be online

Tags: java, jdbc

I have built an application in java using swing core classes. I have used database connection with MS Access on my pc using JDBC:ODBC. I want this application to be online. 
How i can do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly do you mean by "I want this application to be online"?

Comment: What i meant by 'I want this application to be online' is that i want it users not to install it and use it like a java applet.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Java Web Start

Comment: Andre i think that too ... but i am not able to find a good tutorial . I do not use eclipse or any ide , i just code on notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an Applet then you should first read a tutorial like that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

But you will run into problems using a Microsoft Access database from an Applet. Access is not a client server database. There is no Access server you can start and access the database via network connection.

There are two alternatives:

- Change your database to a real client server database like Apache Derby or MySQL and connect to the database via network directly from the applet. But there will be some limitations. Usually the database server should be running on the same host as the web server containing the applet (depending on browser security settings). If the client is behind a firewall, the client may not be allowed to connect to the database port. But in a local network this could be an option.
- Implement a server side service which hides the database access (e.g. REST or SOAP with a Tomcat server). If your service runs at the same HTTP port from which your applet is delivered then there is no firewall restriction. Though it would be possible to use a Microsoft Access database at server side, it is not recommended. Access is a desktop database not a server database. So even in this case you should change your database.